# Can not use in_array on special characters

Tags: php

I have this piece of code:

```
$string = "my;string";
$chars = array_merge(range('a','z'), range('A','Z'), range(0,9));
```

Now, if I run a for loop to verify each character of the $string exists in $chars using in_array() function, when it gets to the third char of $string it returns the key value 52, that being the value of the integer 0; Why in_array() is seeing the semicolumn as the integer zero?

Comment: @Veve Actually `in_array` only returns `true` or `false`, never the position.

Comment: that's all the code... even if I place a char inside $chars for exemple if I put _ in it where I run in_array('_',$chars) instead of giving the key of that char it gives me 52 for zero. It's like it can not process any symbols only letters and numbers

Comment: See the third param of `array_keys` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this snippet:

```
var_dump(';' == 0);
```

You might be very surprised to find that PHP will spit out **true**! The behaviour of PHP is often quite counter-intuitive when you don't check the **type** as well. You can't rely on loose comparison alone I'm afraid.

Now trying running this snippit:

```
var_dump(';' === 0);
```

PHP will return **false** - perfect!

Luckily the `in_array` function has a third parameter, which when set to `true` ensures that a strict comparison is used to make sure the type is the same. The simple solution here is to replace every instance of `in_array($char, $chars)` with `in_array($char, $chars, true)` and the problem will go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot that works. I should've paid more atention to the manual. NOTE for who has/had this problem, the same goes for array_search()